# Incremental Encoder / Frequency

Tags: gpio, measuring

Can anyone help. I have a raspberrypi3 with a photoelectric sensor and a 600ppr encoder hooked up. Everything is up and running, im using pigpio to capture my pulses from the encoder and using the sensor measuring an object. 
The object im measuring is accurate to +/-5mm running at 300 meter/per/min. When I try to run above 400 meter/per/minute my reading on the encoder isn't very stable, would it help if I got a lower ppr encoder say 360?.

The calculation to work out if encoder is compatible is revs/per/second x ppr of the encoder . In my case 600ppr.

can anyone tell me what frequency the raspberrypi3 can handle?.

Andy

Comment: What programming language are you using?  You mention 600 encoder steps for one rotation.  You don't explain how many times the encoder rotates for each meter of travel.

Comment: Hi  Sorry, Using python. Basically there are 2300 pulses per meter, so to get that it needs 3.83 revolutions if that makes sense?.

Comment: That make 400*2300 or 920,000 pulses per second.  By default pigpio only samples 200,000 times a second so it would miss lots of updates.  Python would be swamped at continuous updates at anywhere near that rate.

Comment: Hi no per minute?

Comment: Should be 15333 pulses per second right?

Comment: Im using callback , then when the pulses reach 2300 that adds an extra meter to my counter, then in the main part of my program (pygame) I work out how long 10 meters took using time function divide that by 60 secs then x10 to get meters per minute.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it should be 920,000/60 or 15333 pulses per second.  That should not present a problem on a Pi3 (which should handle about 60000 pulses per second).  I'd be looking to check that nothing else is using a lot of time and how things are scheduled).

Comment: Ok Joan , thank you, I guess there is a lot of checking in the main loop, ive changed the gpu to 32 think that helped a bit, any other tips much appreciated. Im using this system on a fast moving machine counting and measuring cartons on a production machine. So you can set a tolerance and anything different to the preset tolerances and machine stops.   I don't quite understand classes , would I benefit much from them?. Ive learnt a little but not enough, theres a lot to take in when your messing with electronics at the same time lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55547/discussion-between-andrew-wanstall-and-joan).